# Including images in python program?

Tags: python, icons, pyqt4, pyside

I have what is basically a custom version of PySide for creating plotting applications. 
The folder structure is as follows:

```
Juji/
    Images/
    juji/
    Tests/
```

Where the inner 'juji' folder contains the package. The 'Images' folder contains icons which are used in the package and referenced relatively, e.g:

```
QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Images/chart_edit.png'), 'Plot', self)
```

When I create an example UI script in the 'Tests' folder and import juji, everything works fine and the icons show.

If I create an external project and try to import 'juji' into it, the GUI shows, but none of the icon pictures show.

I have tried moving the 'Images' folder inside the 'juji' folder, but this doesn't help.

None of the icons are explicitly used outside of the package - surely it should not matter where my external project is relative to it? (I have added it to the PYTHONPATH).

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How load images properly with Python (pyqt)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842668/how-load-images-properly-with-python-pyqt)

Answer (score 0):

I did a fix which is a bit cludgy:

I moved 'Images' inside juji and created a `guidata.py` file.

In `guidata`, I get the absolute path from the `__file__` attribute, remove the filename and append the 'Images' folder.

I can then import `guidata` to each module in the package and use the absolute path to get the icon files. This seems to work with any other external project.

It is a bit of a hack though. A working relative filepath would be much neater, but I just cant seem to get it working.