# How can resources be provided in PyQt6 (which has no pyrcc)?

Tags: python, pyqt, resources, pyqt6, pyrcc

The [documentation for PyQt6](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pyqt5_differences.html) states that

> Support for Qt’s resource system has been removed (i.e. there is no `pyrcc6`).

In light of this, how should one provide resources for a PyQt6 application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has been [some discussion](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-September/043209.html) on the PyQt mailing list when this was found out.

The maintainer is not interested in maintaining pyrcc anymore as he believes that it doesn't provide any major benefit considering that python already uses multiple files anyway.

The easiest solution is probably to use the static methods of QDir [`setSearchPaths()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setSearchPaths) or [`addSearchPath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#addSearchPath).

The difference will be that resources will be loaded using the *prefix* used for the methods above.

Considering the previous situation:

```
icon = QtGui.QIcon(':/icons/myicon.png')
```

Now it would become like this:

```
# somewhere at the beginning of your program
QtCore.QDir.addSearchPath('icons', 'path_to_icons/')

icon = QtGui.QIcon('icons:myicon.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution since it requires minimal modification of any existing code. I imagine the alternative (using a generic resource system) must require something like `QIcon(QPixmap.loadFromData(data))` - and that wouldn't work for vector images.

Comment: @biqqles not necessarily: using the [solutions provided by ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104738/2001654) will still get you access to the file paths in the correct way. Take a look a the whole mail thread linked in the answer, IIRC there should be a couple of messages about that.

Comment: I looked through the thread again - do you mean [this message](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-September/043228.html) with links to qutebrowser's code? I think I still prefer the neatness of `addSearchPath` but it may well be less robust when it comes to packaging. Both solutions are good but I could only pick one!

Comment: When you create an `exe` with `pyinstaller`, then the `path_to_icons` contents are automatically load to the archieve (or must be putted in the exe folder and if yes where)?

Comment: Yes. This works flawlessly. Also means I can set the path programatically with my Python code and then access it from qss. I'm very happy with the maintainer's decision. The resource system was a bit clunky.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**:

As of PyQt-6.3.1, it's possible to use Qt’s resource system again. (This version now includes the `qRegisterResourceData` and `qUnregisterResourceData` functions which are required by the generated python resource module.)

There's still no pyrcc6 tool, but Qt's own [rcc tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/rcc.html) can now be used to convert the qrc file. This tool should be installed by default with a full Qt6 installation, but if you can't find it, you could also use the PySide6 tools to convert the qrc file. (PySide6 simply searches for the Qt6 rcc tool and runs it using `subprocess`, so it will produce exactly the same output).

Thus, to convert the qrc file, you can now use either:

```
rcc -g python -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

or:

```
pyside6-rcc -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

However, it's very important to note that the import line at the top of the generated file must be modified to work correctly with PyQt6:

```
# Resource object code (Python 3)
# Created by: object code
# Created by: The Resource Compiler for Qt version 6.4.0
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

# from PySide6 import QtCore <-- replace this line
from PyQt6 import QtCore
```

The whole operation can be done with this unix one-liner (requires [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/)):

```
rcc -g python resources.qrc | sed '0,/PySide6/s//PyQt6/' > resources.py
```

or:

```
pyside6-rcc reources.qrc | sed '0,/PySide6/s//PyQt6/' > resources.py
```

Once this small change has been made, the generated module can be safely imported into the main application, like this:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from test_ui import Ui_Window
import resources

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Note that it is **NOT SAFE** to use the generated module without making the changes noted above. This is because the *unmodfied* module will attempt to import PySide6, which is obviously inappropriate for a PyQt6 application. Whilst it may *seem* to work on the development machine, there's no guarantee that mixing the two libararies in this way will always remain compatible - and in any case, it's bad practice to enforce the installation of PySide6 on a user's system just so that they can run a PyQt6 application.

---

*OLD ANSWER*:

The consensus seems to be that the existing python facilities should be used instead of pyrrc. So the resources would be stored directly in the file-system (perhaps within archive files), and then located using [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) (python >= 3.7), or [pkg_resources](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api), or a third-party solution like [importlib_resources](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Exactly how this maps to existing uses of pyrcc will probably be application-specific, so some experimentation will be needed to find the best approach.

For more details on how to use these facilities, see:

- [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028000/984421)

Comment: How did you know that qRegisterResourceData and qUnregisterResourceData functions are available since PyQt-6.3.1? :) I am just curious about the way you know it:)

Comment: @iMath The PyQt source code has `Changelog` and `NEWS` files which summarise this kind of information. The [download page](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) also includes a link to the latest changelog.

Comment: Thank you! Inspired by your answer , I provide mine at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78056570/1485853

Answer (score 2):

for those people who want a real and simple solution just watch it here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5BLPTkbaM8)

a guy figured it out by converting the "resource.qrc" into a .py file by using the pyrcc of PySide6. then importing the resource.py (same as before) in your PyQt6 project. everything is the same, including the special filepath syntax: ":/image.jpg" instead of "./image.jpg"

hope it helps, always feels good to have a simpler solution.

Comment: This is a bad solution because it forces the installation of PySide6 on the user's system. It should never be necessary to do this in order to run a PyQt6 application.

Answer (score 2):

Someone decided pyrcc6 wasn't useful and no longer provide it.  However, what they don't understand is how useful it is for those of us that use qt designer to define our resources like icons.. etc and then using pyinstaller to package and find all resources, so that pyinstaller can build a stand-alone exe and these icons are properly embedded and used in the .ui user interface.

You may find this link useful (I had no success with it though): https://pypi.org/project/pyqt6rc/

Ultimately, I switched from pyqt5 to pyside6 using pip which includes pyside6-rcc command to do the same thing that the old pyrcc5 command used to do.  BTW pyqt6 has way too many enumeration and that makes transistion to pyqt6 painful, which is another good reason to change to pyside6.

The best full explanation can be found at this YouTube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5BLPTkbaM8

Answer (score 1):

I liked the answer by musicamante, but I could not apply it directly since I use Qt Designer and pyuic6 to generate the python code for the UI. I did however find a workaround. It builds on using a resource file in Qt Designer, since I already did that with the previous PyQt versions.

1. Make sure that the path of the resources in the resource (.qrc) file is identical to the folder path. In this example, I have icons in a folder called "icons".

```
    <RCC>
      <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>icons/myicon.png</file>
      </qresource>
    </RCC>
```

2. Run pyuic6 to generate the python code.
3. Patch the generated python code by replacing the resource path e.g. ':/icons/' with 'icons:' in all path strings. I did that with sed, e.g.

```
    sed 's/:\/icons\//icons:/g' pyuic6_output_file.py > patched_file.py
```

4. In your manually written python code, define the prefix using a relative path from the python file location. This makes sure that the paths are searched related to the folder where the python file is located and not relative to a current working folder. That is what is critical to make it work with pyinstaller.

```
    QtCore.QDir.setSearchPaths("icons", [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'icons')])
```

5. For pyinstaller, use the add-data option to add the folder containing the resources, e.g. --add-data ".\icons:.\icons". They are not added automatically by pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [ekhumoro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104738/1485853) and [K.Mulier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658216/1485853), I'd provide my code to automatically convert the .ui and .qrc files, just put  the following code to a file named `ui2pyqt6usingPySide6.py` in a folder that shares the same parent dir as your .ui and .qrc files, then all you need to do is to run it.
Note that you should ensure PySide6(`pip install -U PySide6`)  installed before using it.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import sys
# >>> sys.base_exec_prefix
# 'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32'
# >>> sys.base_prefix
# 'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32'
# >>> sys.exec_prefix
# 'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32'
# >>> sys.prefix
# 'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32'
# >>>


# pyqt
# uicPath = os.path.join(sys.base_exec_prefix, "Scripts/pyuic6.exe")

# uicPath = os.path.join(sys.base_exec_prefix, "Scripts/pyuic5.exe")
# rccPath = os.path.join(sys.base_exec_prefix, "Scripts/pyrcc5.exe")

# print(uicPath)
# pyside
uicPath = os.path.join(sys.base_exec_prefix, "Scripts/pyside6-uic.exe")

rccPath = os.path.join(sys.base_exec_prefix, "Scripts/pyside6-rcc.exe")


def convert(processArgs):
    # ENCODING = 'utf8'
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(processArgs)  # ,用了 universal_newlines=True 本地解析会出解码问题"--debug"  http://www.iqiyi.com/  出现异常
    except Exception as e:
        print('no ', processArgs)
    else:
        print('yes ', processArgs)
        # return str(output, ENCODING)  # output.decode(ENCODING)  #
        with open(outputFilePath, "r+") as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)## Move the cursor to the beginning of the file
            f.write(data.replace('PySide6', 'PyQt6'))
            f.truncate()# Remove any remaining content after the modified part


with os.scandir(os.curdir) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith('.ui'):
            # print(entry.name, entry.path)
            outputFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(entry.path), 'Ui_{}.py'.format(entry.name[:-3]))
            convert([uicPath, entry.path, '-o', outputFilePath])
        elif entry.name.endswith('.qrc'):
            # print(entry.name)
            outputFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(entry.path), '{}_rc.py'.format(entry.name[:-4]))
            convert([rccPath, entry.path, '-o', outputFilePath])







# ================================================================================================ #
#                                       ENUM CONVERTER TOOL
                                        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658216/1485853
# ================================================================================================ #

from typing import *
import os, argparse, inspect, re
q = "'"

help_text = '''
Copyright (c) 2022 Kristof Mulier
MIT licensed, see bottom

ENUM CONVERTER TOOL
===================
The script starts from the toplevel directory (assuming that you put this file in that directory)
and crawls through all the files and folders. In each file, it searches for old-style enums to
convert them into fully qualified names.

HOW TO USE
==========
Fill in the path to your PyQt6 installation folder. See line 57:

    pyqt6_folderpath = 'C:/Python39/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6'

Place this script in the toplevel directory of your project. Open a terminal, navigate to the
directory and invoke this script:

    $ python enum_converter_tool.py
    
WARNING
=======
This script modifies the files in your project! Make sure to backup your project before you put this
file inside. Also, you might first want to do a dry run:

    $ python enum_converter_tool.py --dry_run
    
FEATURES
========
You can invoke this script in the following ways:

    $ python enum_converter_tool.py                   No parameters. The script simply goes through
                                                      all the files and makes the replacements.
                                                      
    $ python enum_converter_tool.py --dry_run         Dry run mode. The script won't do any replace-
                                                      ments, but prints out what it could replace.
                                                      
    $ python enum_converter_tool.py --show            Print the dictionary this script creates to
                                                      convert the old-style enums into new-style.
                                                      
    $ python enum_converter_tool.py --help            Show this help info

'''

# IMPORTANT: Point at the folder where PyQt6 stub files are located. This folder will be examined to
# fill the 'enum_dict'.
# pyqt6_folderpath = 'C:/Python39/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6'
# EDIT: @Myridium suggested another way to fill this 'pyqt6_folderpath'
# variable:
import PyQt6
pyqt6_folderpath = PyQt6.__path__[0]

# Figure out where the toplevel directory is located. We assume that this converter tool is located
# in that directory. An os.walk() operation starts from this toplevel directory to find and process
# all files.
toplevel_directory = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.dirname(
        os.path.realpath(
            inspect.getfile(
                inspect.currentframe()
            )
        )
    )
).replace('\\', '/')

# Figure out the name of this script. It will be used later on to exclude oneself from the replace-
# ments.
script_name = os.path.realpath(
    inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
).replace('\\', '/').split('/')[-1]

# Create the dictionary that will be filled with enums
enum_dict:Dict[str, str] = {}

def fill_enum_dict(filepath:str) -> None:
    '''
    Parse the given stub file to extract the enums and flags. Each one is inside a class, possibly a
    nested one. For example:

               ---------------------------------------------------------------------
               | class Qt(PyQt6.sip.simplewrapper):                                |
               |     class HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(enum.Enum):            |
               |         Round = ... # type: Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy   |
               ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    The enum 'Round' is from class 'HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy' which is in turn from class
    'Qt'. The old reference style would then be:
        > Qt.Round

    The new style (fully qualified name) would be:
        > Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.Round

    The aim of this function is to fill the 'enum_dict' with an entry like:
    enum_dict = {
        'Qt.Round' : 'Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.Round'
    }
    '''
    content:str = ''
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='replace') as f:
        content = f.read()

    p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s+=\s+\.\.\.\s+#\s*type:\s*([\w.]+)')
    for m in p.finditer(content):
        # Observe the enum's name, eg. 'Round'
        enum_name = m.group(1)

        # Figure out in which classes it is
        class_list = m.group(2).split('.')

        # If it belongs to just one class (no nesting), there is no point in continuing
        if len(class_list) == 1:
            continue

        # Extract the old and new enum's name
        old_enum = f'{class_list[0]}.{enum_name}'
        new_enum = ''
        for class_name in class_list:
            new_enum += f'{class_name}.'
            continue
        new_enum += enum_name

        # Add them to the 'enum_dict'
        enum_dict[old_enum] = new_enum
        continue
    return

def show_help() -> None:
    '''
    Print help info and quit.
    '''
    print(help_text)
    return

def convert_enums_in_file(filepath:str, dry_run:bool) -> None:
    '''
    Convert the enums in the given file.
    '''
    filename:str = filepath.split('/')[-1]

    # Ignore the file in some cases
    if any(filename == fname for fname in (script_name, )):
        return

    # Read the content
    content:str = ''
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='replace') as f:
        content = f.read()

    # Loop over all the keys in the 'enum_dict'. Perform a replacement in the 'content' for each of
    # them.
    for k, v in enum_dict.items():
        if k not in content:
            continue
        # Compile a regex pattern that only looks for the old enum (represented by the key of the
        # 'enum_dict') if it is surrounded by bounds. What we want to avoid is a situation like
        # this:
        #     k = 'Qt.Window'
        #     k found in 'qt.Qt.WindowType.Window'
        # In the situation above, k is found in 'qt.Qt.WindowType.Window' such that a replacement
        # will take place there, messing up the code! By surrounding k with bounds in the regex pat-
        # tern, this won't happen.
        p = re.compile(fr'\b{k}\b')

        # Substitute all occurences of k (key) in 'content' with v (value). The 'subn()' method re-
        # turns a tuple (new_string, number_of_subs_made).
        new_content, n = p.subn(v, content)
        if n == 0:
            assert new_content == content
            continue
        assert new_content != content
        print(f'{q}{filename}{q}: Replace {q}{k}{q} => {q}{v}{q} ({n})')
        content = new_content
        continue

    if dry_run:
        return

    with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='replace') as f:
        f.write(content)
    return

def convert_all(dry_run:bool) -> None:
    '''
    Search and replace all enums.
    '''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(toplevel_directory):
        for f in files:
            if not f.endswith('.py'):
                continue
            filepath = os.path.join(root, f).replace('\\', '/')
            convert_enums_in_file(filepath, dry_run)
            continue
        continue
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = 'Convert enums to fully-qualified names',
        add_help    = False,
    )
    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help'    , action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dry_run' , action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--show'    , action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.help:
        show_help()
    else:
        #& Check if 'pyqt6_folderpath' exists
        if not os.path.exists(pyqt6_folderpath):
            print(
                f'\nERROR:\n'
                f'Folder {q}{pyqt6_folderpath}{q} could not be found. Make sure that variable '
                f'{q}pyqt6_folderpath{q} from line 57 points to the PyQt6 installation folder.\n'
            )
        else:
            #& Fill the 'enum_dict'
            type_hint_files = [
                os.path.join(pyqt6_folderpath, _filename)
                for _filename in os.listdir(pyqt6_folderpath)
                if _filename.endswith('.pyi')
            ]
            for _filepath in type_hint_files:
                fill_enum_dict(_filepath)
                continue

            #& Perform requested action
            if args.show:
                import pprint
                pprint.pprint(enum_dict)
            elif args.dry_run:
                print('\nDRY RUN\n')
                convert_all(dry_run=True)
            else:
                convert_all(dry_run=False)
    print('\nQuit enum converter tool\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I started to use PyQt6, I found missing full support for Qt6 Resources.
Especially when using designer and using images for buttons, labels etc.
I tried addSearchPath, but still had to edit generated .py template.
After some research I found using importlab the best solution for my problem.

I made simple script, which is using .qrc file and generates .py templates with importpath.

For example changing:

```py
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icon1.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.State.Off)
```

to:

```py
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
with path("myPackage.resources.icons", "icon1.png") as f_path:
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(str(f_path)), QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.State.Off)
```

Here is a link to GitLab repo: https://github.com/domarm-comat/pyqt6rc

Or install via pip:

```
python3 -m pip install pyqt6rc
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding further to youtube video **(Update 28/12/22)** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5BLPTkbaM8

**Do it with the simple script:**

```
pyuic6 tip.ui > tip.py && sed -i '10iimport _cf_rc\nimport _rc_rc' tip.py
```

**Explaination here:**

```
sed -i "10i' -> means insert from the 10th line onwards.
```

**I have 2 files to insert in tip.py:**

```
import _cf_rc

import _rc_rc
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here who is migrating from pyqt5:

The migration from pyqt5 to pyside6 turned out to be easier for me than going from pyqt5 to pyqt6 since we get `pyside6-rcc` and `pyside6-uic`

Easy way to add Apple Silicon/M1/M2 support to a legacy app

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34624552)