# Migrating to Qt6: Is there a method to finding long-form names?

Tags: pyqt5, migration, pyqt6

I am migrating a codebase of PyQt5 to PyQt6.  I read the stackoverflow question another user asked:

[Migrating to Qt6/PyQt6: what are all the deprecated short-form names in Qt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086632/migrating-to-qt6-pyqt6-what-are-all-the-deprecated-short-form-names-in-qt5)

My question is simply a variation of this, ie, in my case I've spent several hours trying to find the longer form for the following:

```
def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.QFlags:
    return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
```

Error received:

> AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'ItemFlags'.

Previously I've been able to figure out the long-form equivalent required in Qt6, but in this case I can't figure it out.  (When this one is solved, I will probably have to find the equivalence for
the return values in the code example above: Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled, etc.)

I would have been happy to have posted this in the form of a comment under the other posted question, but stackoverflow says I need 50 reputation pts to comment.

Comment: All you needed to do is use the search page in the Qt Docs: e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/search-results.html?q=ItemIsDropEnabled. The first hit in the results gives "enum, ItemFlag { NoItemFlags, ItemIsSelectable, ..." . Unfortunately, following the link doesn't go straight to the relevant section, but you can easily find it via your browser's page-search command (i.e. Ctrl+F, or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "flags" (*plural* form) refers to the combination of enum values, which instead refer to each single value (see the [documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qflags.html#details)).

As written in the comment of the answer you linked, the PyQt maintainer seems to be very resistant to any "shorter" solution, and he chose to always use the Enum namespace for Python consistence even for flags, and even if some Qt enum/flag names are *not* consistent for backward compatibility; this might be very confusing, not to mention the fact that this obviously means *even longer* code lines (and we all know how we already struggle with the length of Qt object names).

To clarify, here's a typical and confusing case (in Qt terms, and valid with PyQt5):

- `Qt.AlignCenter` is a `Qt::AlignmentFlag`, but its actually an enum (even if it's named "flag"); see the result for PyQt5:

```py
    >>> test = Qt.AlignCenter
    >>> print(type(test))
    <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag'>
    >>> print(test)
    132
```

- `Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter` results in a `Qt::Alignment`, but it's actually a flag, even if it's actually equal to `Qt.AlignCenter`:

```py
    >>> test = Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter
    >>> print(type(test))
    <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.Alignment'>
    >>> print(test)
    <PyQt5.QtCore.Alignment object at 0xb30ff41c>
    >>> print(int(test))
    132
```

In any case, the point remains: if you want to use a *value*, you must use the *enum* namespace, which is `Qt.ItemFlag` without the trailing "s".

```py
def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.QFlags:
    return (
        Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled 
        | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled 
        | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable 
        | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable 
        | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDragEnabled
    )
```

Remember to always refer to the official C++ API documentation of classes and objects in order to understand the different types and get their proper names: none of the Python docs are good for that, both PyQt *and* "Qt for Python" (aka, PySide).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same problem this morning and to expand a bit with an example.

If you look on [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextcursor.html) of the Qt documents.

At the top of the page you will see:

```
enum    SelectionType { Document, BlockUnderCursor, LineUnderCursor, WordUnderCursor }
```

Farther down the page you see the description of SelectionType:

```
enum QTextCursor::SelectionType
QTextCursor::Document   3   Selects the entire document.
```

In PyQt6 it's

```
cursor.select(QTextCursor.SelectionType.Document)
```

JT

Comment: When I follow that link, I don't see  "enum SelectionType { Document, BlockUnderCursor, LineUnderCursor, WordUnderCursor }" at the top of the page.  When I do a search for 'enum' on the page, it found 8 results, the first was MoveMode, then MoveOperation, etc.

These days I find I can somewhat guess from the list that vscode suggests while entering the fully qualified string.  And also going to the docs as you did and simply searching for the word 'enum' usually gets me what I need.  Also I find myself doing a vscode global search through my previous uses.

Comment: it's the 13th line down on that page under Public Types...