# Text aside and below an image in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am preparing a catalog for a small library. All books with main data are displayed. Next to each title there is a button that must show the cover image and a short description of the content. Something like this.

[image]Until now I have not found anything that could help me, all the options present in `designer` do not allow to have the text arranged as I would like

Comment: You will need to use a `QWebEngineView`. Widgets like `QLabel` and `QTextEdit` only support a [limited subset of HTML4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). The CSS isn't sophisticated enough to produce that kind of text layout.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: @ekhumoro Actually, it is sophisticated enough, since the `float` property is supported for tables and images.

Comment: @musicamante Well, that is really weird because when I tried `float` yesterday, I couldn't get it to work. Somehow, the image was positioned on the right, but always ended up *below* the text, no matter where I inserted it. As far as I can recall, I used the Qt Designer text-edit dialog on a QLabel with just a simple block of text and a single image tag, with no other html. But when I try the same thing today, I cannot reproduce the previous behaviour. Presumably, there was something weird about the text I copied yesterday that messed up the preview somehow. Never mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve that layout using Designer, because the layout management of Qt always considers objects (widgets) having a rectangular shape, even if they contain text: text based widgets are just like other "rectangular widgets" and their content is not considered nor changed based on the "shape" of other elements in the layout: Qt layout managers ***always*** consider widgets as rectangles.

It can be done, though, using rich-text based widgets like QLabel (discouraged for this purpose<sup>[1]</sup>) or [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), by embedding the image in the document<sup>[2]</sup>, since the [(limited) HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) provided by the Qt rich text engine [supports](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties) the basic [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) property<sup>[3]</sup> for images and tables.

The following basic HTML can be used with [`QTextEdit.setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop):

```html
<img src="path/to/image.png" style="float: right;">
Some very long text...
...
...
...
```

Here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of the example]

The only issue is the path of the image.

If the image is stored with the [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), use that path (`src=":path/in/resources"`)<sup>[4]</sup>.

If the image is a local file, then just use python formatting with the path to that file, and ensure that that path is correct (consider that relative paths always use the *working* directory, which is the path from which the python interpreter is launched).

If the image is loaded internally (for instance, from the network) and *not* stored as a physical file, you can use the [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding to show the image:

```py
import base64
# ...

# assuming "imageData" is a Python "bytes" object
base64data = base64.b64encode(imageData).decode()
html = '''
<img src="data:image/whatever;base64,{}" style="float: right;">
'''.format(base64data)

# to avoid escaping of curly brackets for format() or f-string
html += '''
Some very long text...
'''

textEdit = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
textEdit.setHtml(html)
```

Note that the *value* of `data:` in `<img src="">` is actually pointless: you only need to provide the `data:` part, the value is actually not that relevant since Qt just uses [`QImage.loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData) and automatically guesses the format from the file using [QImageReader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html). The result is the same that you would get by doing `img = QImage('myimage')` even if you don't specify the format and the file name has no specific/valid extension. This also obviously means that if the file/data is corrupted, the image might not be shown (and a "broken image" icon will be shown as a placeholder).

If the image was retrieved through Qt (for instance, using `QFile.readAll()` or downloaded with QNetworkAccessManager), then the the raw data is stored as a [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html), and the base64 data used above can be created with the following:

```py
base64data = imageData.toBase64().data().decode()
```

as in:

```py
# - encode using base64, as another QByteArray:
qtBase64 = imageData.toBase64()
# - convert it to a Python "bytes" object (b"..."):
pyBase64 = qtBase64.data()
# - make it a string:
base64data = pyBase64.decode()
```

The above is also valid if the image is stored on a database as raw data.

<sup>[1] QLabel obviously lacks direct support for scrolling, and it also has some [important limitations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues) when using rich text contents (most importantly, word wrapped contents) and the label is part of a complex layout.</sup>

<sup>[2] QLabel actually uses [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) features internally, which enables rich text features (most importantly, word wrapping; see the above note) whenever it detects what could possibly be HTML formatted content (based on the return value of [`Qt.mightBeRichText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-sub-qtgui.html#mightBeRichText)).</sup>

<sup>[3] Remember that the current Qt rich-text support is **based** on HTML4 and CSS2.1, so the only valid values of `float` are: `left`, `right` and `none` (the default). The CSS `inherit` value is also not supported.</sup>

<sup>[4] Be aware that PyQt6 dropped support for the `pyrcc` utility, but resource files can still be used (since they're implemented on the Qt side, not in Python) and built with the `rcc` utility provided by Qt: they added the `-g python` flag, similarly to what done for `uic`, which creates python compatible resource files. You only need to edit the import statement of the generated file to avoid issues (remember that PyQt and PySide can ***not*** be used together, and PySide might not be installed in the target system). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104738) answer.</sup>

Comment: It's perfect. I had to adapt part of my code to your suggestions but in the end everything was OK. Now I just have to resize the image and, if possible, the scrollbar. Thank you

Comment: You can specify a reference dimension in the `<img>` tag and it will show the image scaled to that dimension while keeping the aspect ratio. The scroll bar, instead, is part of the *widget*, so you cannot "style" it as you could in a web browser. Depending on your needs, there is some level of customization. Eventually consider using Qt Style Sheets (see the [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar), but also carefully read the QSS documentation).

Comment: I searched my old HTML scripts and found the answer to resize the image (height = x and width = y) at the end of <img. The scrollbar can wait