# Widget background not showing PyQt6

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt6

I created a registration widget in qt designer.I am importing the second file into the first one. When I run the code instead of my background is a white window. And there should be a picture that is in the repository. Although the link to the background itself is present

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog,QFileDialog
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from ui_imagedialog import Ui_ImageDialog
from AboutTheProgram import Ui_AboutTheProgram


class MainWindows(QDialog,Ui_ImageDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.MainMenu = Ui_ImageDialog
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushLogin.clicked.connect(self.TransitionAboutTheProgram)
        # При нажатии на кнопку login перейти на новую страницу
    def TransitionAboutTheProgram(self):
        abouttheprogram=AboutTheProgram()
        window.addWidget(abouttheprogram)
        window.setCurrentIndex(window.currentIndex()+1)



class AboutTheProgram(QDialog,Ui_AboutTheProgram):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.abouttheprogram = Ui_AboutTheProgram
        self.setupUi(self)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
mainwindow=MainWindows()
window.addWidget(mainwindow)



window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

ul_imagedialog.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_ImageDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, ImageDialog):
        ImageDialog.setObjectName("ImageDialog")
        ImageDialog.resize(445, 514)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=ImageDialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 370, 480))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#pushLogin{\n"
"    background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.505682, x2:1, y2:0.477, stop:0 rgba(20, 47, 78, 219), stop:1 rgba(85, 98, 112, 226));\n"
"    color:rgba(255,255,255,210);\n"
"    border_radius:5px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushLogin:hover{\n"
"    background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.505682, x2:1, y2:0.477, stop:0 rgba(40, 67, 98, 219), stop:1 rgba(105, 118, 132, 226));\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushLogin:pressed{\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    background-color:rgba(105,118,132,200);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlDiscord{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"    color:rgba(85,98,112,255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlDiscord:hover{\n"
"    color:rgba(155,168,182,220);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlDiscord:pressed{\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    color:rgba(115,128,142,255)\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlGitHub{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"    color:rgba(85,98,112,255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlGitHub:hover{\n"
"    color:rgba(155,168,182,220);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlGitHub:pressed{\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    color:rgba(115,128,142,255)\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlFacebook{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"    color:rgba(85,98,112,255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlFacebook:hover{\n"
"    color:rgba(155,168,182,220);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlFacebook:pressed{\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    color:rgba(115,128,142,255)\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlYouTube{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"    color:rgba(85,98,112,255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlYouTube:hover{\n"
"    color:rgba(155,168,182,220);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#pushUrlYouTubek:pressed{\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    color:rgba(115,128,142,255)\n"
"}")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 300, 420))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/image/1618615593_15-phonoteka_org-p-temno-sinii-tsvet-fon-16.jpg);\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.widget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 280, 390))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(3)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,0,0,100);\n"
"border-radius:25px;")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.widget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 90, 121, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color:rgba(255,255,255,210)")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 150, 200, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"border-bottom:2px solid rgba(108,118,132,255);\n"
"color:rgba(255,255,255,230);\n"
"pading-bottom:7px;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 220, 200, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"border-bottom:2px solid rgba(108,118,132,255);\n"
"color:rgba(255,255,255,230);\n"
"pading-bottom:7px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.widget)
        self.pushLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 290, 200, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushLogin.setFont(font)
        self.pushLogin.setObjectName("pushLogin")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.widget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 350, 201, 21))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color:rgba(255,255,255,140);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushUrlDiscord = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.widget)
        self.pushUrlDiscord.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 400, 30, 30))
        self.pushUrlDiscord.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Social Media Circled")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushUrlDiscord.setFont(font)
        self.pushUrlDiscord.setObjectName("pushUrlDiscord")
        self.pushUrlGitHub = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.widget)
        self.pushUrlGitHub.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 30, 30))
        self.pushUrlGitHub.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Social Media Circled")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushUrlGitHub.setFont(font)
        self.pushUrlGitHub.setObjectName("pushUrlGitHub")
        self.pushUrlFacebook = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.widget)
        self.pushUrlFacebook.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 400, 30, 30))
        self.pushUrlFacebook.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Social Media Circled")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushUrlFacebook.setFont(font)
        self.pushUrlFacebook.setObjectName("pushUrlFacebook")
        self.pushUrlYouTube = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.widget)
        self.pushUrlYouTube.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 400, 30, 30))
        self.pushUrlYouTube.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Social Media Circled")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushUrlYouTube.setFont(font)
        self.pushUrlYouTube.setObjectName("pushUrlYouTube")

        self.retranslateUi(ImageDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ImageDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, ImageDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ImageDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("ImageDialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "Login in"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("ImageDialog", "User Name"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("ImageDialog", "Password"))
        self.pushLogin.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "L o g i n"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "Введите ваш логин и пароль"))
        self.pushUrlDiscord.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "Y"))
        self.pushUrlGitHub.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", ")"))
        self.pushUrlFacebook.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "E"))
        self.pushUrlYouTube.setText(_translate("ImageDialog", "P"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63QRn.png)
Position be so

And output like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbTNV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using a resource file (`.qrc`) for the image.

These files cannot be used directly in python, and require the use of the `pyrcc` tool, which creates a "compiled" python file that contains all resources when it is imported.

Unfortunately, the PyQt developer chose to stop supporting that tool since Qt6, claiming that, since python packages already use multiple files, having a single file for resources doesn't make a lot of sense (I understand his point of view, but I don't agree with it; he's the maintainer, though, and that's his choice).

Luckily, there's a solution: you can use the `pyrcc5` tool (available with PyQt5), then open it and change the import statements on top from PyQt5 to PyQt6.

Otherwise, just don't use resources, and directly point to physical files.

Also see this related question: [How can resources be provided in PyQt6 (which has no pyrcc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66099225)